# Kill established tcp connection on Linux

Tags: linux, tcp

How can you kill an established TCP connection on Linux?

Comment: kill the process holding open the connection?

Answer (score 1):

There's a tool called [`tcpkill`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tcpkill). You can usually get it by installing `dsniff`.

```
[root@fresh ~]# tcpkill -i eth0 tcp port 22
tcpkill: listening on eth0 [tcp port 22]
```

Comment: Uhm. Who marked this community wiki ?

Comment: Apparently you did.  There is only 1 revision.  And says "[made Community Wiki]".  http://stackoverflow.com/posts/7985103/revisions - weird though, maybe an accidental click on the wiki checkbox?

Comment: @chown Maybe :)

Answer (score 0):

[`tcpkill`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tcpkill) is the command to research, let's you kill connections to / from a specified host, network or port.

> For example, to prevent any connections to the host www.google.com use this command:
>
> ```
> /usr/sbin/tcpkill −9 host www.google.com
> ```